# Converting QGIS2 Plugins to QGIS3

Tags: qgis, python-3

I am trying to convert a QGIS2 Plugin to QGIS3; specifically the Quickfinder plugin (I am aware of QGIS3 Locator and no I do not feel it provides the same or similar capability just thought I would get that out of the way). I used a Python 27 to Python3 converter to check the code and I changed some import module lines and qt4 to qt5 and resolved some initial errors.

The error I am getting now is

> no module named 'core' C:...\qgis-ltr./python\qgis\utils.py line 335.

Can anyone help me understand this one and where I would start looking for to fix it?

Comment: did you look at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3 and especially https://github.com/opengisch/qgis2to3

Comment: I did install and try to follow the guides but I cannot get the command to be recognized or it says the files are missing. Python says it is all installed so not sure what is up; I might be using it wrong or I don't have it all installed properly. Other have had the problem but I didn't see any solutions yet...